I cannot import CSV to QGIS
I try to add layer > add delimited text layer open CSV. file of coordinate set point coordinates (latitude, longitude) but it doesn't work (cannot show point show only document file layer).
Here is link to may data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g4MzktGVgJJBFoNbldIYPxn8kS-WpU73/view?usp=sharing
How do solve this problem?

Can you share one record from your CSV file ?

sure
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g4MzktGVgJJBFoNbldIYPxn8kS-WpU73/view?usp=sharing

Below is your solution.

The issue is that your CSV file has too many extra lines with empty data (you also have unnecessary empty colums):

Use Excel and delete all the unnecessary records.: (You can select the data and paste it in a new sheet then export the new sheet to a csv file)

Do the same to delete the unnecessary columns.
I tried again, and it works perfectly:


